# Can we add new attributes to jpa entities in java?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I have generated JPA entities from the database in net beans. I have a table called user with 3 fields firstname,lastname and birthdate. Now this value returns date type. I want it to be returned as string from the database itself. So I added a new attribute called "dateStr" in the User and stroing the converted string value into it. That's working fine but other methods which are generated by default are taking this column as the column in database and are failing. For example I have a default method "FindUserByFirstName" now this is taking the new column which I adding in the class and trying to read it from database which fails. How can I make sure that this column is ignored by the the query? Thanks.

Comment: Make "dateStr" attribute as transient.

Comment: Can you post your code entity?

Comment: If it's a date, don't use a String to represent it. Use a Date. That doesn't prevent you to have *methods*, in your entity or elsewhere, to transform the date into a String (although this should be the role of the presentation layer, and it should deal with internationalization). No need for a new attribute. Think about it: if you set the String to 2012-01-01 and the date to 2014-12-31, and both are mapped to the same column, what should JPA do?

Comment: @Gayathri tried using transient but it did not work.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks will try to use the approach you have mentioned.